# Regexmatch PCRE parse last name

Tags: autohotkey, pcre

I'm trying to parse the first and last name into their own variables.  I figured out how to get the first name, but I can't get the last name.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm reading the data off the clipboard.

```
Clipboard = John Smith

RegExMatch(clipboard, "(^([\w\-]+))", FirstName)

RegExMatch(clipboard, "      ", LastName)
```

Comment: This is [very difficult in general](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

For this very specific example, you could probably use `$` at the end instead of `^` at the beginning, as in `"(([\w\-]+)$)"`.